# How do i boot any ISO from a USB flash drive?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, iso, bios

So I know in my bios theres this settings in USB labled "Emulate device" HDD/CDROM/FDD
But im not even sure I understand what it means and I cant find it on the internet.

Do you remember the old samsung - U3 - virtual cdrom - usb disks? 
Thats what I want to do can anyone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try unetbootin. That usually works for most iso's if i'm not wrong. As for the Emulate device option, i guess that just emulates the usb disk as a sata/scsi or cdrom device.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick. The link has details of how to boot iso file and install ubuntu from flash usb drive. It also has snapshots and results which will guide you.

http://www.rapo.org/linux/BootableLinuxUSBDriveHowTo.html. This link should help you. You can try this link also http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide detail on the link here please! Thanks!

Comment: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/. Check this link. It has snapshots also.